# How to skip resource file not to be obfuscated?

Tags: javafx-2, obfuscation, proguard, executable-jar

I am obfuscating JAR and that JAR also contains some resource files. I do not want them to get obfuscated or get corrupted. How to ask proguard to ignore resource file such as public key store file?

```
-adaptresourcefilenames
-adaptresourcefilecontents
```

We have to options for resources file but from both these options my public key store file get corrupted into output jar and throwing exception -

```
Exception in Application start method
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.a(Main.java:642)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherIm
        pl.java:403)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:
        47)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitiali
        zed keystore
        at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseNotary.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)
        at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseNotary.verify(Unknown Source)
        at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseManager.verify(Unknown Source)
        at de.schlichtherle.license.LicenseManager.verify(Unknown Source)

        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29
        )
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
        ... 1 more
        Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitialized keystore
        at java.security.KeyStore.isKeyEntry(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options accept arguments to filter the files that you want to adapt:

cfr. ProGuard manual > Usage > [-adaptresourcefilenames](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#adaptresourcefilenames) / [-adaptresourcefilecontents](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#adaptresourcefilenames)

Comment: So you are saying that I do not need to mention the public key store file with these progaurd options. Does it?